# java inheritance - do I need an array?

Tags: java, inheritance

I need a generic base class called *building* that stores the number of floors a building has, the
number of rooms, and its total square footage. I also need a derived class called *house* that inherits
*building* and stores the number of bedrooms and bathrooms, and another
derived class named *office* that too inherits *building* and stores the number of fire extinguishers and
telephones.

I have to create a Java Application program that demonstrates this class hierarchy and provide all necessary
methods. The classes have to be tested using the following main method.

```
public class TestBuildings 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    building building1 = new building(1, 10, 6000);
    building building2 = new building();
    System.out.println();

    house house1 = new house(1, 5, 3000);
    house house2 = new house(2, 2);
    System.out.println();

    office office1 = new office(1, 2, 15000);
    office office2 = new office(2, 6, 15000, 6, 30);
    System.out.println();

    //change building properties
    building2.setFloors(3);
    building2.setRooms(12);
    building2.setFeet(20000);
    System.out.println("Building 2: \n" + building2.toString() + "\n\n");

    //change house properties
    house1.setBedrooms(3);
    house1.setBaths(3);
    house2.setFloors(2);
    house2.setRooms(10);
    house2.setFeet(4200);
    System.out.println("House 1: \n" + house1.toString() + "\n\n");
    System.out.println("House 2: \n" + house2.toString() + "\n\n");

    //change office properties
    office1.setFireExt(4);
    office1.setTelephones(50);
    System.out.println("Office 1: \n" + office1.toString() + "\n\n");
 }
}
```

This is what I have for class *building*

```
public class building 
{
 private int floors;
 private int rooms;
 private int sqft;

 public void setFloors(int floors)
 {
    this.floors = floors;
 }

 public int getFloors()
 {
    return floors;
 }

 public void setRooms(int rooms)
 {
    this.rooms = rooms;
 }

 public int getRooms()
 {
    return rooms;
 }

 public void setFeet(int sqft)
 {
    this.sqft = sqft;
 }

 public int getFeet()
 {
    return sqft;
 }
}
```

This is my class *house*

```
public class house extends building
{
 private int bedrooms;
 private int baths;

 public void setBedrooms(int bedrooms)
 {
    this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
 }

 public int getBedrooms()
 {
    return bedrooms;
 }

 public void setBaths(int baths)
 {
    this.baths = baths;
 }

 public int getBaths()
 {
    return baths;
 }
}
```

And finally, class *office*

```
public class office extends building
{
 private int fire;
 private int phones;

 public void setFireExt(int fire)
 {
    this.fire = fire;
 }

 public int getFireExt()
 {
    return fire;
 }

 public void setTelephones(int phones)
 {
    this.phones = phones;
 }

 public int getTelephones()
 {
    return phones;
 }
}
```

My question, what to I have to add, subtract, or modify in my three classes to make the main method work? Do I need arrays in there somehow?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: And....? What's the problem you're having? Does the main method currently *not* work? If not, what is it supposed to be doing, and what is it doing?

Also, naming conventions are your friends. `house extends building` --> `House extends Building`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create constructors with parameters for your building, house and office. For example, for building:

```
public building(int floors, int rooms, int sqft) {
    this.floors = floors;
    this.rooms = rooms;
    this.sqft = sqft;
}
```

Constructing building without specified parameters has no sence for me - so the building should have specified floors, rooms, sqft, at least you should provide some default values:

```
public class building {
    private int floors = 1;
    private int rooms = 1;
    private int sqft = 1; // Have no idea what is default value here
    ...
}
```

Then you define house as class extended from building. This means that your class house *is a* building and floors, rooms and sqft *must* be specified to construct it:

```
 public class house extends building {
    private int bedrooms;
    private int baths;

    public house(int floors, int rooms, int sqft) {
       super(floors, rooms, sqft);
    }
    ...
 }
```

Again, having constructor of house with just bedrooms and baths has no sence, sinse there is no information about floors,rooms,sqt specified, so you cannot intitialize building correctly.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it doesn't explain how he can use **super(floors, rooms, sqft)** from office, and house.

Comment: Can you please explain the use of super(floors, rooms, sqft) from office and house? @WalterM

Comment: I get it now. Thanks! @Nyavro

Answer (score -1):

```
public class building implements java.io.Serializable
{
 private int floors;
 private int rooms;
 private int sqft;

 public void setFloors(int floors)
 {
    this.floors = floors;
 }

 public int getFloors()
 {
    return floors;
 }

 public void setRooms(int rooms)
 {
    this.rooms = rooms;
 }

 public int getRooms()
 {
    return rooms;
 }

 public void setFeet(int sqft)
 {
    this.sqft = sqft;
 }

 public int getFeet()
 {
    return sqft;

 }
}
```

Comment: this 3 class should implements serializable building ,house , office